# Swift - Calculating elapsed time takes too long?

Tags: swift, datetime, nsdate, elapsedtime

My server call gives me JSON data with a date time per piece of data and I want to calculate the time elapsed between now and then and load it into my data structure. The way I'm doing it now takes way to long, is there a different design practice I should be using? The follow function is what I am using right now

```
func dateDiff(_ dateStr:String) -> String {
    var timeAgo = "10m"

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "AST") as! TimeZone


    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "AST") as! TimeZone

    let now = formatter.string(from: Date())

    if let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr){
        if let nowDate = formatter.date(from: now){
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day,.hour,.minute,.second], from: date, to: nowDate)
        let sec = components.second
        let min = components.minute
        let hours = components.hour
        let days = components.day
        if (sec! > 0){
            if let secc = sec {
                timeAgo = "\(secc)s"
            }
        }
        if (min! > 0){
            if let minn = min {
                timeAgo = "\(minn)m"
            }            }
        if(hours! > 0){
            if let hourss = hours {
                timeAgo = "\(hourss)h"
            }
        }
        if(days! > 0){
            if let dayss = days {
                timeAgo = "\(dayss)d"
            }
        }
    }
  }
    return timeAgo
}
```

Comment: Where is the difference between `formatter` and `dateFormatter`? The latter seems to be unused. Why do you convert `Date()` to a string and back to a `Date`?

Comment: Have a look at [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance reasons, you should pull the instantiation of the date formatter out of the method, because that's notoriously computationally intensive.

I'd also suggest using a `DateComponentsFormatter` to simplify the formatting of the elapsed time.

So, define your two formatters:

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let _formatter = DateFormatter()
    _formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"
    _formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    _formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "AST")  // Curious; we usually use `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` (i.e. GMT/UTC/Zulu)
    return _formatter
}()

let componentsFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let _formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    _formatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
    _formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
    return _formatter
}()
```

And then your function is considerably simplified:

```
func dateDiff(_ string: String) -> String? {
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string) else { return nil }

    return componentsFormatter.string(from: date, to: Date())
}
```

Also note that:

- I used `TimeZone` directly, rather round-tripping through `NSTimeZone`;
- I set the `locale` to be `en_US_POSIX`, which you should [always use](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html) if the source of the date strings is a web service or database;
- I eliminated the conversion of “now” to a string and back; just use `Date()` directly;

The only other thing that looks suspicious is the use of `AST` for the timezone. Usually date strings are saved in GMT/UTC/Zulu (e.g., RFC 3339 or ISO 8601). If you have control over that, that's probably best practice, avoiding problems if users change time zones;

Answer (score 1):

Your code was too verbose to begin with, you could have shortened it significantly:

```
if let day = components.day, day > 0 {
    timeAgo = "\(day)d"
} else if let hour = components.hour, hour > 0 {
    timeAgo = "\(hour)h"
} else if let minute = components.minute, minute > 0 {
    timeAgo = "\(minute)m"
} else if let second = components.second, second > 0 {
    timeAgo = "\(second)s"
}
```

---

But the better way to do it is to use `DateComponentsFormatter`, available since iOS 8 and OS X 10.10:

```
let componentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
componentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day]
componentsFormatter.maximumUnitCount = 1
componentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated

let timeAgo = componentsFormatter.string(from: dateComponents)!
```

Here are some example of what it does for you:

```
let dateComponents1 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, day: 1, hour: 4, minute: 6, second: 3)
let dateComponents2 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, day: 0, hour: 4, minute: 6, second: 3)
let dateComponents3 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, day: 0, hour: 0, minute: 6, second: 3)
let dateComponents4 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, day: 0, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 3)

print(componentsFormatter.string(from: dateComponents1)!) // 1d
print(componentsFormatter.string(from: dateComponents2)!) // 4h
print(componentsFormatter.string(from: dateComponents3)!) // 6m
print(componentsFormatter.string(from: dateComponents4)!) // 3s
```

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat expensive to create and then DateFormatter objects each time `dateDiff` is called.  If the object that owns `dateDiff` is created once per app launch or JSON load, one thing you can do to optimize is to make your date formatters a member of the class, so you don't recreate it every single time you call `dateDiff`.

In other words, put:

```
var formatter : DateFormatter
var dateFormatter : DateFormatter
```

at the top of your class and then initialize it in an `init` function.